# Java: Combining "not" clauses in regex

Tags: java, regex

I'm trying to find a substring that contains a "]" without a "|" in front of it. How can I possibly do this with regex?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`/(?<!\|)\]/` is the regex you need.

`?<!` is a zero-width assertion also known as "negative lookbehind." This essentially means match `]`, but "look behind" and assert that the previous character isn't a `|`

Comment: @user941401 Yes: http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html

Comment: @NullUserExceptionఠ_ఠ don't you need to double escape | and ] ?

Comment: @FailedDev Yes, but this is not my answer. I just added an explanation on what `?<!` is.

Comment: Just FYI, the leading and trailing slashes are not part of the regex.  Many people include them for traditional reasons, but I think that causes unnecessary confusion.  The regex is `(?<!\|)\]`; if you were using it in Perl you would probably write it as `/(?<!\|)\]/`, but in Java source code it should look like this: `"(?<!\\|)\\]"`.

Comment: Thank you NullUserException for the added clarification - I was going to clarify but couldn't do so in a way that satisfied me >_>. And thank you Alan Moore for the further clarification.

Answer (score 2):

```
/(?<!\|)\]/
```

Use negative lookbehind.

For java :

```
Pattern regex = Pattern.compile("(?<!\\|)\\[");
```

Answer (score 1):

Very simply: `[^|]\]`.

If you also want to match a `[` at the beginning of a string, use `(^|[^|])\]`

Comment: Won't match the string `"]"`.